# Set icon as cursor pointer in CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I want to set icon as curse pointer in JavaScript. I try some default cursor style. See below code.

```
<span style="cursor:pointer">auto</span><br>
```

But I want to set my icon as cursor. Example:- "cursor : My Icon" .

How would i set this in CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should used cursor: url(image.png) like:

```
span {
   cursor: url(cursor.png), auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but I want to used icons. Not image.

Comment: icons instead of images, like .ico?

Comment: @chirag Whats wrong with this? You can save your icons as images, svg or even gif.

Comment: I tried to applied property using this "cursor= url('resources/find.png')". It is not working. Showing Invalid property value in Google chrome.

Comment: @Pik_at is correct - you are missing the fall-back that he included ... the spec calls for an image URL and comma separated fall-back (in his example, auto).

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS:

```
   span{ cursor:url('http://www.dolliehost.com/dolliecrave/cursors/cursors-all/animals01.gif'), auto }
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/omvq5n9e/2/)

Comment: i tried to set gif file which is on my system. But it is not working.  span{cursor:url('D:\project\Demo\1234.gif'), auto}

Comment: @chirag it doesn't work in fiddle. check it in your local system and don't use backward slash, use forward slash like this ('D://project/Demo/1234.gif')

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct, but if you want to do it in jquery you can do this:

```
$('selector').css( 'cursor', 'url(cursor.ico)' );
```

Comment: Learn english and understanding questions - noone said sth. about jQuery, he even explicitly wrote "in CSS".
Secondly it's obvious how to do it in jQuery if you know the CSS. ;)

Comment: Don't trash talk kid, iam not englidh and try my best. And he did say "I want to set icon as curse pointer in JavaScript", so what about keeping your words for you, hmm?.

Comment: I'm neither an native english speaker. ;)
Well, sorry for my kinda mean comment. But still, it was going about CSS, not JS. He did a mistake in his first sentence, he didn't meant JavaScript as you can see from the context.